# How to send SMS to mobile numbers in Slack through API?

Tags: slack

I am integrating Slack with my product. I am able to send chat messages to slack channels using API. But I want to send an SMS text message to external numbers through Slack using API. Is it possible to do so? IF so where can I find the API documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible without using any other third party application.

Comment: If so, then do add the list of those 3rd party applications. It will help others working on similar project.